# JMeter, graph of the trend of errors (percentage) during the test

Tags: graph, jmeter

I would like to extract some information about the progress of the error from the .jtl log file of jmeter. In particular I am looking for if there is a jmeter plug-in or an external library able to draw me on a graph with the trend of the error percentage during the time span of the test execution.

Answer (score 0):

If you're looking for the information "during the test" in form of chart - the only option I can think of is using [Backend Listener](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Backend_Listener), you could get something like:

[image]

More information:

- [Real-time results](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/realtime-results.html)
- [How to Use Grafana to Monitor JMeter Non-GUI Results - Part 2](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-to-use-grafana-to-monitor-jmeter-non-gui-results-part-2)

In [command-line mode](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/get-started.html#non_gui) JMeter shows summary of requests and throughput:

[image]

Comment: Hi Dimitri thanks for the suggestions. But if want execute a post processing of ".jlt" log file, there are any tools or jmeter listner which allow me to see on a graph how the percentage of error varies? (that is what we already see in the execution in non-gui mode as you reported, but in graphic terms, even by varying the granularity since the report in non-gui mode is updated every 30s)

Comment: 1. [HTML Reporting Dashboard](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/generating-dashboard.html) has Response Codes per Second chart. 2. [Transactions Per Second](https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/TransactionsPerSecond/) chart has separate line for transaction failures. 3. [Response Codes per Second](https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/ResponseCodesPerSecond/) chart is a replica of point 1. 4. Summarizer update frequency in command line mode can be controlled using `summariser.interval` [JMeter Property](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/apache-jmeter-properties-customization)

Comment: This tools gives me the failure occurrences for each istant of the time,but they do not report the trend of the PERCENTAGE of error during the test..